# How can I get process by name?

Tags: c#, foreach, process

How can I get process by name?

For example, if the process name is "Test", it will do nothing, but if there isn't a name "Test", it will say `MessageBox.Show("Cannot find process Test");`

I used

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Test"))
{
    //do nothing
}
```

However, `foreach` doesn't have `else`, and I can't do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Test");

if(processes.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot find process Test");
}
else
{
    foreach(var process in processes)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netcore-3.1):

> Returns
>   [Process[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1)
>   An array of type [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1) that represents the process resources running the specified application or file.

Which tells us `GetProcessByName` will return an array of processes that share the same process name.

Instead, we can simply just check if the array is empty:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Test");

if (processes.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot find process Test");
} 
else
{
    // found processes
    // iterate and do something with them
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Which will only show the message from the `if` block if no processes with the name `"Test"` could be found. Otherwise, you can iterate the found processes and do something with them in the `else` block.